# Using instanceof on granparent class to abstract class with non-abstract children classes

Tags: java, class, subclass, instanceof

I'm having a problem with my code. I have an a grandparent class, an abstract parent class that have non-abstract children

```
public class GrandParent () {
// codes here
}


public abstract class Parent1 extends GrandParent () {
// codes here
}

public class A extends Parent1 () {
// codes here
}

public class B extends Parent1 () {
// codes here
}
```

i have another class which is where i put everything. i created an arraylist of grandparent class which contains the children of the parent class. When i tried using instanceof it gave me an error and i dont understand why. The parent class is a subclass of the granparent but why does error occur?

```
public class Main () {
    ArrayList <GrandParent> gps;

    public Main () {
       gps = new ArrayList<> ();

       gps.add(new A());
       gps.add(new B());

    }

    public void method () {
       if(gps.get(0) instanceof Parent1) {   // in here i get an error that says inconvertible types; cannot cast GrandParent to java.util.Parent1
           //codes
       }
```

Comment: Why is your code in `java.util`?

Comment: Don't paraphrase error messages. Copy and paste the exact and complete error message.

Comment: Please post your error message because I can't reproduce your error, it works fine for me

Comment: inconvertible types; cannot cast GrandParent to java.util.Parent1 this is the error when in the line itself. im using intellij thats why i can see the error per line.

when i run it, the error says java: incompatible types: GrandParent cannot be converted to java.util.Parent1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a few issue here. First the main method in class `Main` needs to be `public static void main (String[] args)`. This is what Java is expecting for the `main` method. Then the `ArrayList` needs to be static, otherwise it can't be referenced if it is defined at the class level. Alternatively, you could define gps within the `main` method and then pass it to `method()` as an argument.

Also notice that you are putting `()` after the names of your classes. That's not correct. Only methods should have parameter lists.

Now the code is in a state where any other problems can be fixed. Remember that, `instanceof` should be able to cast to a parent type to do the check. It does NOT matter if the parent type is abstract or not. This is NOT relevant. So there's no reason why it shouldn't be able to check if `A` and `B` are of the `Parent1` type. It doesn't matter if `Parent1` is abstract. To prove this, have a look at the small example below.

```
public class Main {

        public static void main (String [] args) 
        {
            GrandParent baz = new A();
            GrandParent biz = new B();

            if (baz instanceof Parent1)
               System.out.println("hi");

            if (biz instanceof Parent1)
               System.out.println("hi again");
        }
}
```

If you run this, there are no errors and the output "hi" and "hi again" are both printed. This is similar to what is happening in your code because the elements in your `ArrayList` gps are `GrandParent` references to objects of type `A` and `B`.

Here is your code with the corrections applied. Note that each class goes in it's own file, since they are all public classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class GrandParent {
// codes here
}


abstract class Parent1 extends GrandParent {
// codes here
}

class A extends Parent1 {
// codes here
}

class B extends Parent1 {
// codes here
}



public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<GrandParent> gps;

    public static void main (String [] args) {
       gps = new ArrayList<>();    

       gps.add(new A());
       gps.add(new B());


    }

    public static void method () {
       if(gps.get(0) instanceof Parent1) {   // in here i get an error that says inconvertible types; cannot cast GrandParent to java.util.Parent1
           {
             //Codes here 
           }

       }
    }
}
```

But there's one other thing. From a software design perspective, it is not a good idea to make your code dependent on type checking. In other words, the behavior of your program should not depend on explicitly checking types like this. It is better to define that behavior within the class itself. For example, you can override methods in the child classes to define behavior which is different from that of its ancestor. Similarly, you can provide implementations of interfaces in a class. Notice neither of these approaches require explicit type checking at all.